# Exact time for custom notifications in Android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am developing an Android application for counseling services. Client can view their scheduled appointment in app. For example,

**Next appointment:** Dec 31 2016 10:00AM

Now I need to do that user will receive 2 notifications – reminders about appointment. One on 7 days before and another on 3 days before. I save this date (Dec 31 2016 10:00AM) as a `String` so I can extract year, month, etc.
I found that I need to write some kind of service which will send these notifications. This is what I tried (is not completed):

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);
        Notification nBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Don't miss! ")
                .setTicker("Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_logo)
                .setContentText("7 days left till your appointment...")
                //.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nBuilder.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(1,nBuilder);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And method that I don't know from where to call:

```
public void reminder() {
    Intent intent  = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);

    AlarmManager manager =(AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            0,intent, 0);
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent);
}
```

For testing purposes I have set hour/minute/second manually but obviously I will need to extract it from date `String`.

Comment: @Reaz: could the removal of those `import` lines make it harder for a reader to understand the problem?

Comment: Imports make the question long I think. So I removed those. Imports are often un-necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write an `IntentService` first. Here's an example, you can write code for showing the notification in `processNotification` function.

```
public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";

    public NotificationIntentService() {
        super(NotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    public static Intent createIntentStartNotificationService(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_START.equals(action))
                processNotification();

        } finally {
            WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void processNotification() {
        Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);
        Notification nBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Don't miss! ")
                .setTicker("Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_logo)
                .setContentText("7 days left till your appointment...")
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nBuilder.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(1, nBuilder);
    }
}
```

And then create a `NotificationEventReceiver`

```
public class NotificationEventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE";

    public static void setupAlarm(Context context, long interval) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, alarmIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Intent serviceIntent = null;
        if (ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE.equals(action)) {
            serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
        }

        if (serviceIntent != null) {
            startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}
```

And the `NotificationServiceStarterReceiver`

```
public final class NotificationServiceStarterReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long interval = getIntent().getLongExtra("alarm_interval", 0);
        NotificationEventReceiver.setupAlarm(context, interval);
    }
}
```

Add these in your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `<application>` tag

```
<service
    android:name="YourPackage.NotificationIntentService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />

<receiver android:name="YourPackage.BroadcastReceiver.NotificationEventReceiver" />
<receiver android:name="YourPackage.BroadcastReceiver.NotificationServiceStarterReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now from your `Activity` you may call the `setupAlarm()` inside `onCreate` function.

```
NotificationEventReceiver.setupAlarm(getApplicationContext(), interval);
```

You need to add `WAKE_LOCK` permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Here you see you can pass the `interval` of the next notification to be shown. Use the `interval` wisely. You might consider saving the current statuses of the appointment in the database and then trigger the alarm when necessary by passing proper interval of next alarm. That's the idea.

**Update**

So in your case, you don't want to show the notification when user is logged out. So in this case, you might consider keeping a `SharedPreference` to store the login status. You might call the `processNotification` function based on the value stored.

So the pseudo code may look like this.

```
if(pref.getBoolean("login_status", false)) {
    // If the login status is true, process the notification
    processNotification();
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But instead of setRepeating I used simple set, because I need one-time notification. Yet, could you tell me how can i cancel these notifications, for example, when user logouts it is no longer useful to show notifications (I check login status in main activity onPause method). I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, you forgot to mention that i needed to add wake_lock permission in manifest file.

Comment: And what about cancelling notifications?