# Setting a notification on a specific date(fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, notifications, alarmmanager

I am trying to make a notification pop up on a certain date and time. The variables are fine, I have tested them out. This is the code that's not working for me.

```js
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationPublisher.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 001, intent, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminder.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Exactly nothing happens. At all. I can't figure out why. This is the code that I got fromt the first post that popped up on google. The only reason I changed anything is because I'm working inside a fragment.

```html
Calendar sevendayalarm = Calendar.getInstance();

sevendayalarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 001, intent, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sevendayalarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

I will add a of my manifest and NotificationPublisher.java file in text form. Hopefully someone can figure out what the problem is...

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<service android:name=".NotficationPublisher" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter> <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" /></intent-filter>
</service>
```

NOTIFICATIONPUBLISHER.JAVA

```html
package com.vraces.vitte.senae;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import junit.framework.Test;

/**
 * Created by CmdrVraces on 2017-01-15.
 */

public class NotificationPublisher extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
        long[] pattern = {0, 300, 0};
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 01234, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.warning)
                .setContentTitle("Take Questionnaire")
                .setContentText("Take questionnaire for Duke Mood Study.")
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(01234, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: [link](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/android-sdk-add-a-repeating-alarmmanager-to-the-autostart-displaying-messages-in-the-notification-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 001, intent, 0);
```

to

```
PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 001, intent, 0);
```

Because your `NotificationPublisher` is a `Service` and not a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem few weeks ago and the answer from this link helped me to solve the problem: [Exact time for custom notifications in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407084/exact-time-for-custom-notifications-in-android/41411169#41411169)
Of course you will need some modifications but I hope it will show you the right way...